# Allow app to communicate with web domain

Tags: java, android, html, web

I have a domain that is user posts based. I plan to create a user posts based app like 9gag. I need the app to be able to communicate and fetch data hosted from my domain.

Things I need the app to do:

1) Allow users to post pictures though the app.

2)Allow users to leave comments through the app.

3)Allow users to leave 'likes' though the app.

I want the data to be stored on my domain, while when a user opens the app, the app will fetch this data from the domain and display it for the user. How can I make my app communicate with the domain?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do this would be to implement an API on your domain that your app can send requests to.  I cannot explain all this in detail here because it would require a lot of space and a full blown tutorial, but I can tell you what to research and what to implement to make this happen.

1. First off you need to create an API for your app to send requests to.  I suggest a "RESTful" api as they are pretty strait forward to the average programmer.  Here is a good video that explains what an API is and a little bit of how they are typically implemented. https://youtu.be/7YcW25PHnAA
2. After you have an API setup, you have "encode" the information so that it is easy to parse once your app has a hold of all that information.  To do this we use a "data-interchange format".  One of the big ones being used today is JSON, see their website to learn more here: http://www.json.org/  JSON is pretty strait forward and easy to understand if you have a concept of what Programming: objects, strings, arrays etc are.
3. Ok so you have gotten your information from the server, you have parsed it from the JSON you got, and displayed all your content... now, what do you do if your user give a thumbs up or comment on something?  This is also implemented via the API,  this part should be easiest for you, it involves wrapping up the required data (Content id, user id, what they did [ie liked the content]) and send this via a http request, just like how you got your information in the first place, but instead of reading the data response, now we are just sending the HTTP request from the app, and we don't care what happens next (on the app level) its up to the server to record the data from the HTTP request.

I would highly suggest looking up how to create API and look through some tutorials... there are a lot of tutorials out there that want you to modify the HTACCESS file on the server, this is really necessary (Boy I hope I don't get crucified for saying that; fellow Stack Overflow Citizens, if you disagree, please explain your reasoning) Obviously for a large mainstream website, the whole HTACCESS file might be a good idea, but for a beginner, I don't think it is really needed.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer.  However I still have a few questions:
1) I installed the wordpress JSON API plugin for my domain. Will that suffice?
2)Could you elaborate on how I could "encode" the information to parse? I'm not new to android and java, but I'm new to this.
Thanks alot man!

Comment: Sorry but my experiece with wordpress is limited,  someone else will have to tell you how to accomplish this via wordpress... maybe ask a new question with the tag "wordpress" and ask how you would impliment a RESTful api (or an api in general) through wordpress?